# Double Reference Source. Self referencing equality (==) operator

Tags: c#

I was reviewing the implementation of some primitive types, specifically `System.Double` in .NET's [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,1a65cbdb09544ba1) and I stumbled upon this:

```
[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public static bool operator ==(Double left, Double right) {
    return left == right;
}

[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public static bool operator !=(Double left, Double right) {
    return left != right;
}
```

I know that this kind of self referencing operator implementations can be a decompiler issue as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974612/767890), but I was under the impression that the code shown in the Reference Source was actual source code and not the output of a decompiler.

Can anyone explain whats really going on here?